# Is it possible to use buck boost converter at the same time?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, boost

I have a input source from 50mV to 4V and I want a fixed/regulated voltage of 3V. Input voltage is varying every time so in order to achieve the 3V I have to implement Buck as well as Boost converter with respect to the input voltage.

I couldn't find any chip/IC which operates at such a low voltage 50mV, So what could be the solution for this?  Do I need to detect the input voltage before using Buck/Boost converter?

Comment: 50mV does not seem like a power input to me. Are you trying to amplify a signal or get power from a very low voltage power source?

Comment: Do you have an idea of duration of input at each level?  What current sourcing is possibly at each voltage level?

Comment: There are buck-boost and boost-buck (aka Çùk converter) that do what you want. But for such input, you may need to consider other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

50mV as a power source is energy harvester range, meaning the device operation will be sporadic at best. There are few devices from Linear which start working from ~200mV, depending on the energy source.

Comment: The energy source is thermal, the voltage varies from 50mV to 4V so if I want to get 3 V at the output I will have to use Buck as well as boost depending on the input voltage, is there a way to detect what voltage is coming? 
I did see some IC from LT but didn't really find the exact one I am looking for.

Comment: I think it will be enough just to apply a load to the energy source for the voltage to drop.